# parabola function for any duration

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a parabola for a specific time interval (could be 4,5,1,etc).

this is the code currently.

```
const calculateParabolaPoint = (x) => Math.abs(-Math.pow(x - 2, 2) + 4);
```

where x is the time counter in hours (so for time period 9am, with a duration of 4, the first counter will return 0, then 1, etc.).

I want this to create a parabola that returns to 0 for any duration and currently a bit confused how to approach it. I've tried passing in y for duration, i.e., (x,y), and replacing the 4 value with the y value, but it doesn't return properly.

Would love some help here - thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. What do you mean by a parabola for a duration? Do you want a curve that intersects the X axis at 2 specific points?

Comment: yes, so at the beginning and the end it hits 0 at the x axis

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
const parabola = (start, end) => x => (x - start) * (x - end)
```

By basic math if `x == start` the whole thing will be multiplied by 0 thus the result is 0. Same logic for if `x==end`. We know parabolas only intersect the axis at upto 2 points if scale is non-0.

If you distribute the terms you would get `x**2 - x * start - x * end + start * end` which would match the form given.